# Is there a way to remove pre-start buffer from the MediaRecorder?

Tags: javascript, web-mediarecorder

I am using `MediaRecorder` to record microphone input in a web application.

Based on some testing with Chrome v100, the recorded audio contains about 100ms of data from before the `MediaRecorder.start()` function is called. I determined this by calling `.start()` in the event handler for a `click` event on a button. In the resulting audio file, the mouse click is audible. I believe this should be impossible if the recorder does not record data until after the `click` event is fired.

Here's the resulting audio file in Audacity. The first waveform is the release of the mouse button, and the second is a pure 440Hz tone that is triggered by the same `click` event.

[image: Screen shot of wav file in Audacity]

Is there a way to either remove this pre-`.start()` portion of the audio file or know how long it is? My application requires that the audio file is synced as closely as possible to the actual `start` event.

Here's the [code](https://github.com/jodeleeuw/media-recorder-latency/blob/main/test.html) that I used for this test, and [here's a live version on GitHub Pages](https://jodeleeuw.github.io/media-recorder-latency/test.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <button id="setup">Setup</button>
    <button id="start" disabled>Start Recording</button>
    <div id="audio"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    let audioContext; 
    let stream;
    let recorder;
    const recorded_chunks = [];

    async function getRecorder() {
      audioContext = new AudioContext();

      stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: false,
      });
      recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

      recorder.addEventListener("start", handleRecorderStart);
      recorder.addEventListener("stop", handleRecorderStop);
      recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", handleDataAvailable);
    }

    function handleRecorderStart(){
      setTimeout(stopRecording, 1500);
    };

    function handleDataAvailable(e){
      if (e.data.size > 0) {
        recorded_chunks.push(e.data);
      }
    }

    function handleRecorderStop(){
      const data = new Blob(recorded_chunks, { type: "audio/webm" });
      const audio_url = URL.createObjectURL(data);
      document.querySelector("#audio").innerHTML = `<p><audio id="playback" src="${audio_url}" controls></audio></p>`
    }

    function playTone() {
      const note = audioContext.createOscillator();
      note.frequency.value = 440;
      note.connect(audioContext.destination);
      note.start(audioContext.currentTime);
      note.stop(audioContext.currentTime + 1);
    }

    function startRecording() {
      recorder.start();
    }

    function stopRecording() {
      recorder.stop();
    }

    document.querySelector("#setup").addEventListener("click", () => {
      getRecorder();
      document.querySelector("#start").disabled = false;
    });

    document.querySelector("#start").addEventListener("click", () => {
      playTone();
      startRecording();
    });
  </script>
</html>
```